# Python, eclipse, mac, struggling to get selenium working

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, selenium

I installed the selenium package and now trying to run it in eclipse. It seems to be importing fine but then it wont load the webdriver for any browser. This is the error its giving

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 65, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.45.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 88, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env).communicate()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I checked and the folders and files are all there so im not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have firefox installed?

Comment: @alecxe oops!!! i feel so stupid, i didnt have it installed. I didnt realise i needed to as i thought the drivers would be used from the selenium bundle. Thanks for pointing out my stupidity! It works great now.